# How can I get more Tools in Visual Studio Pro 2013 for UML Class Design?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, visual-studio-2013, class-diagram

I want to create an UML class diagram in Visual Studio Professional 2013 but it only shows me these options. I need composition, aggregation, etc. What can I do to get all those?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 Professional Edition does not support UML diagrams.  You need VS2013 Ultimate for that support.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409437(v=vs.120).aspx

The class diagram options you are seeing are for working with ".Net Class Diagrams".  These options end up creating a lot of potential for confusion (in my opinion) -- Microsoft has a knack for creating multiple editions (SKUS) that are difficult to retain which features are available in each one.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Solution Explorer, right click in the project and choose Add New Item and select UML Class Diagram. See [detailed MSDN introduction.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2014/08/11/working-with-class-diagrams-let-visual-studio-2013-do-the-work.aspx)